# Trying to create a User account in Active Directory Using C#. Get an invalid dn syntax error

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to create a user account in Active directory using the following code.  When I tried to execute the code I get an invalid DN syntax error.  I checked the DN information via the ADSI edit tool and an LDAP search tool and it matches what I put in the code.  I tried various logins and it still fails.  My code it below.  Some information regarding the domain and login has been altered for this post.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.Protocols;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;

namespace NewAccount
{
class Program
{
    public struct UserInfo
    {
        public string username;
        public string sAMAccountName;
        public string firstName;
        public string lastName;
        public string displayName;
        public string emailAddress;


    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        UserInfo newUserinfo;
        newUserinfo.firstName = "Tom";
        newUserinfo.lastName = "Pig";
        newUserinfo.displayName = "Tom Pig";
        newUserinfo.emailAddress = "Tompig@domain.k12.or.us";
        newUserinfo.username = "TomPig";
        newUserinfo.sAMAccountName = "tompig";

        string path = "LDAP://CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=k12,DC=or,DC=us";
        DirectoryEntry adUserFolder = new DirectoryEntry(path,"admin","pass",AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

        DirectoryEntry newUser = adUserFolder.Children.Add("CN" + newUserinfo.username, "User");

        newUser.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value = newUserinfo.sAMAccountName;
        newUser.Properties["givenName"].Value = newUserinfo.firstName;
        newUser.Properties["sn"].Value = newUserinfo.lastName;
        newUser.Properties["displayName"].Value = newUserinfo.displayName;
        newUser.Properties["mail"].Value = newUserinfo.emailAddress;

        newUser.CommitChanges();


        newUser.Invoke("setpassword", "P@ssWord!");
        newUser.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = 0x0200;
        newUser.CommitChanges();

        Console.WriteLine("User: " + newUserinfo.username + " successfully created!");
        Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to continue.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think you need to make this line have CN=:

```
DirectoryEntry newUser = adUserFolder.Children.Add("CN=" + newUserinfo.username, "User");
```